# Leaderboards level system discord js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have this xp system and I save each id in a json with a name.
How can I display a top 5 people?
Is there a way to retrieve the data and display 5 at a time?
I would try to sort and after creating a forum to display fixed 5 but I don't know exactly how I could do that.
Any ideas?

```
const xp = require("../../xp.json")
if(!xp[message.author.id]) {
        xp[message.author.id] = {
            xp: 0,
            level:1
        };
    }

    let curxp = xp[message.author.id].xp;
    let curlvl = xp[message.author.id].level;
    let nxtLevelXp = curlvl * 300;
    let difference = nxtLevelXp - curxp;
```

For example, this is how I retrieve the data for display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Object.entries` , here is an example -

```js
const xp = require("../../xp.json");
var top5 = Object.entries(xp).sort((a,b)=>b[1].level - a[1].level).splice(0,5);
```

Try mapping them

Comment: [
  [ '722224138872913931', { xp: 38292, level: 128 } ],
  [ '442320775508885504', { xp: 13140, level: 44 } ],
  [ '272194753316945920', { xp: 10742, level: 36 } ],
  [ '552517770366320650', { xp: 10377, level: 35 } ],
  [ '232817696802373642', { xp: 10396, level: 35 } ]

Comment: I can acces it ? top5[message.author.id] = { xp = xp, level = level} ?

Comment: are you trying to make an embed ?

Comment: 239817696802373642,[object Object]